# Time calculation activity in Php

Tags: php, datetime

I am working on a web application, in which a web user activity is to be block form half hour before of given time.

I need to calculate time half hour before of given time.

Means if a date and time give like `08/04/2015 16:00:00`
now need to calculate time half hour before of the given time i.e. `08/04/2015 15:30:00` during this a web activity is blocked for end user.

Please give me suggestion and sample code in PHP.

Comment: You can create a session and store the time and create a variable $stoptime which will be 30 minutes and you can compare the start time which you stored in the session and the current time and you can proceed accordingly

Answer (score 0):

you can take this for your refrence,
but you need to modify the code as per your requirements

```
$start_time = strtotime("2008-12-13 10:42:00"); // get this time while user loggs in
$end_time = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));// this is dynamic time, it changes everytime when the page is reloaded
$difference_in_minutes = round(abs($end_time - $start_time) / 60,2); // this will return the diference between two times in minutes

if($difference_in_minutes >= 30)
{
 // do you 30 minutes block stuff here
}
```

let me know if any further classification needed